# How to get a null value from database to a checkbox in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want parse null value and disable checkbox in form view
how can i do that
that's my current code:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="FLPCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Full Load Passed" Checked=' <%# (Eval("FullLoadPassed")==DBNull.Value ? false : Eval("FullLoadPassed"))%>' />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Enabled` property of `FLPCheckBox` to `false` in your code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the enabled property, enabled =  (Eval("FullLoadPassed")==DBNull.Value)